# Typed UI and listeners in android

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns

I would like to improve the way i created the following UI. Currently i am creating each tablerow programmatically according to each object's type attribute.

```
class objectDTO {
    private type; //enum        
    public boolean isMultiple(){...}
    public boolean isSingle(){...}
}
```

I am trying to find a more dynamic solution like having a class for each type that might not requires programmatically adding layouts and components as i do in the fragment class,

```
if(objectDTO.isMultiple()) {
    //Create TableRow + Multiple radiobuttons
}
else if(objectDTO.isSingle() {
    //Create TableRow + Add One Checkbox
{
else {
    //Create default invalid object Interface or skip
}
```

Havind a listadapter and applying the different ui there will just move the design problem to other class.

Early thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple solution for you would be to have a class hierarchy-  a base objectDTO class and a child for each type.  When you load the object list, have a factory method create the proper type of object.  Each type would override a `createView` method which would create the view for that type.  Then your table creation function becomes:

```
for(objectDTO object : allObjects){
    View view = object.createView();
    tableView.addView(view, lp);
}
```

But if you're creating a view for an object type, there's always going to need to be someone that dynamically creates view objects (createView in this case), and there's always going to need to be some function that knows what class to make an object (the factory in this case).  Its just a matter of where you want that complexity to be.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, your answer was complete and simple.